# Conditional expectation characterization of sub-$\sigma$-algebra measurability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a complete probability space and $\mathscr{G}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathscr{F}$. I with to show that a random variable $X\in\mathcal{L}^1$ is $\mathscr{G}-$measurable if and only if
$$
E[X\eta]=E[XE[\eta|\mathscr{G}]],\forall\eta\in\mathcal{L}^\infty.
$$
The "only if" statement follows from the definition of conditional expectation and the use of standard method (simple function approximation), and I tried to show the "if" statement by showing $\sigma(X)\subset\mathscr{G}$. However, I got stuck in doing so, and wish to know how I may show $\sigma(X)\subset\mathscr{G}$?

Comment: I have an incomplete idea, which might help you. Imagine that $X \in \mathcal{L}^2$, so that $E[-|\mathscr{G}]=p$ is the orthogonal projection $p$ onto the subspace $\mathcal{L}^2(X, \mathscr{G}) \subset \mathcal{L}^2(X, \mathscr{F})$. Then you condition says that $(X, \eta-p(\eta))=0$ for all $\eta$, so $X \in \mathcal{L}^2(X, \mathscr{G})^{\perp \perp}$.

Comment: @NicolásVilches Your argument is almost complete. All you need is  the fact that $L^{\infty}$ is dense in $L^{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\eta \in L^{\infty}$,
$$E(X\eta) = E(XE(\eta \mid \mathscr{G})) = E(E(X \mid \mathscr{G})E(\eta \mid \mathscr{G})) = E(E(X \mid \mathscr{G})\eta).$$
Taking $\eta$ to be suitable indicator functions, this implies that $X = E(X \mid \mathscr{G})$ a.s.. So $X$ is a.e. equal to a $\mathscr{G}$-measurable function.

Comment: Is it to choose $\eta_1=1_{X\geq E(X|\mathscr{G})},\eta_2=-1_{X<E(X|\mathscr{G})}$?Since $E((X-E(X|\mathscr{G}))\eta)=0$ and $(X-E(X|\mathscr{G}))\eta\in\mathcal{L}_0^+$, we have $X=E(X|\mathscr{G})$ a.e. on both $\{X\geq E(X|\mathscr{G})\}$ and $\{X<E(X|\mathscr{G})\}$?

Comment: @TaylorZhang Yes.